# How to setup convenient ssh to ubuntu 20.04 vm on vmware workstation 16

Tags: networking, ssh, vmware, static-ip

I setup ubuntu server 20.04 LTS as a VM on Vmware Workstation. I want to be able to `ssh` into it from my windows 11 host. Everything works, but the dynamic IP is annoying. When I changed it to a static internal ip it lost connection to the public internet.

The vm is set to use a `NAT` interface and the host can reach it and the public internet. I tried setting a static IP in `netplan` and the host Windows 11.

All I need is a way to `ssh` without looking up it's new IP.

[image: my network information]

If it makes a diffrence, I am using a cloud image from [Canonical's site](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/current/)

Comment: NAT is great if you want your VM to be able to access the internet, but it's awful if you want the internet or LAN to be able to access your VM (like SSH connections). Are you open to other networking methods?

Comment: Yes as long as I can access it from the host and no one outside my network can.

Comment: In virtuabox I always used bridged not nat and it always works for me. I never use vmware though.

Comment: If you're trying to access it from the host, just use a private host only network in VMware, and then manually set a static IP range on the link in the VMware network configuration tool, and then additionally set a static IP on th machine.  Rather than bridging to your network, because then if your computer goes anywhere else with your system it's visible to *that* network as well and not just your computer.

Comment: @petep consider that anyone on the network then can access the system, not just the user's host system.  If this is a desktop that doesn't leave the home net that's fine, but if it's for example on a laptop running VMware Workstation then others will be able to see the system and access/scan it with port scanners, etc.  Defeating the purpose of the NAT network.  I'd use the NAT if you want the host machine to be the only machine to reach the VM.  And it needs updates (via NAT) to security patch it, so it's usually better to use NAT than bridged.